# Why this unit test fail?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, vitest

I am using vitest to run unit testing and have this error with

```
screen.getByText()
```

this is my code
const sqftElement = screen.getByText("$12,500" );

```
// Assert that the element is in the document any assert I do it fails
expect(sqftElement).toBeInTheDocument();
```

});

this is vitest error
his could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

this is how it renders

```
<div
            class="sc-eDnVMP sc-jSwlEQ gqOLWa kWMYxy"
          >
            $ 
            12,500
             
            <span
              class="sc-gKHVLF faTKcL"
            >
               per month
            </span>
          </div>
```

I know I can make match funtion but I canno get it right

run
screen.getByText("$12,500)
this test should pass

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).